# How does Firestore query operation strings treat different data types?

Tags: firebase, operators, google-cloud-firestore

How does the [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) `opStr` (Operation Strings) in the [where](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#where) query method treat different data types?

The different operation strings are: `<, <=, ==, >, and >=`

For `number` data type it is very self explanatory, but how about for the other data types? `string`, `boolean`, `object`, `array`, `null`, `timestamp`, `geopoint`, and `reference`

So for e.g. `string` data type, does `>=` mean **is equal to or contains string**?

So `db.collection('users').where('lastname','>=','bar')` would return all users that has a lastname of bar or contains bar? e.g. `bar`, `foobar`, `barbaz`

Does anyone know of any documentation for this specific subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For string types, the `>=` evaluates based on the [lexicographical ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) of the values.

Some examples:

- `"a" < "b"`
- `"aaa" < "aab"`
- `"abc" < "abcd"`

And also:

- `"000" < "001"`
- `"010" < "011"`
- `"100" < "101"`

But for example:

- `"2" > "10"`

Since the `"2"` is alphabetically later than the `"1"` in unicode.

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful. Explains a lot why I am not getting the data I am expecting. Do you have any idea for the other data types?