# How to sort firebase users based on date?

Tags: javascript, firebase, sorting

I am trying to represent firebase users to a non technical person. He wants the newest users on top. i have this key value pair on every firebase user node called `joinDate`. i want to pull data out based on that.

Here is the code

```
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
            var i = 1;
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log(childData);
            if (childSnapshot) {
                var emailText = childSnapshot.child("userProfile/email").val();
                var joinDateText = childSnapshot.child("joinDate").val();
                var currentPhyxText = childSnapshot.child("userProfile/currentPhyx").val();
                var nameText = childSnapshot.child("userProfile/name").val();
                var lastNameText = childSnapshot.child("userProfile/lastname").val();
                var progressText = childSnapshot.child("userProfile/progress");
                var lastSeenDateText = childSnapshot.child("userProfile/score/lastDate").val();
                var StringifiedProgressText = JSON.stringify(progressText);

                var email = document.createElement("h4");
                var number = document.createElement("h4");
                var joinDate = document.createElement("h6");
                var currentPhyx = document.createElement("h6");
                var name = document.createElement("h6");
                var lastName = document.createElement("h6");
                var lastDate = document.createElement("h6");
                var lowbackData = document.createElement("h6");
                var progress = document.createElement("h6");
                var br = document.createElement("br");

                email.style.display = "inline";               
                number.style.display = "inline";
                lastName.style.display = "inline";
                name.style.display  = "inline";

                joinDate.textContent = "Join Date :  " + joinDateText;        
                currentPhyx.textContent = "Current Phyx : " + currentPhyxText;
                number.textContent = i+") ";
                email.textContent = emailText;
                name.textContent = "Name : " + nameText;
                lastName.textContent = " " + lastNameText;
                lastDate.textContent = "Last Seen Date : " + lastSeenDateText;
                progress.textContent = "Progress : " + StringifiedProgressText;
                progress.textContent = progress.textContent.replace(/{/g, "");
                progress.textContent = progress.textContent.replace(/}/g, "");
                progress.textContent = progress.textContent.replace(/"/g, "");
                progress.textContent = progress.textContent.replace(/,/g, " • ")

                document.body.appendChild(number);
                document.body.appendChild(email);
                document.body.appendChild(joinDate);
                document.body.appendChild(currentPhyx);
                document.body.appendChild(name);
                document.body.appendChild(lastName);
                document.body.appendChild(lastDate);
                document.body.appendChild(progress);
                document.body.appendChild(br); 
                i++;
                }
            });
        });
```

I tried doing

```
ref.orderByChild("joinDate").on('value', function(snapshot) {
...
...
}
```

This doesn't work either my data looks like this :- 
[Firebase image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ1Lf.png)

Comment: What exactly does "this doesn't work" mean? Given that `joinDate` is a String, my guess is the result is ordered by month first or something? You should use a timestamp instead and format it for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `joinDate` properties hold string values in `dd/MM/yyyy` format. Since they are string value, they are ordered lexicographically. And in lexicographical order, for example, `"01/15/2020"` comes before `"21/11/2019"`.

To allow chronological ordering you have two main options:

1. Store the dates as actual `Date` values in Firestore.
2. Store the dates in strings that ensure the lexicographical order it the same as the chronological order, e.g. `"2019-11-21"` comes before `"2020-01-15"`.

Also see:

- [Firebase query by date string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216858/firebase-query-by-date-string) (for Realtime Database, but the exact same problem and solution)
- [How to retrieve data from firebase where the value of a date is 1 month ago from current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206491/how-to-retrieve-data-from-firebase-where-the-value-of-a-date-is-1-month-ago-from)
- [How does Firestore query operation strings treat different data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504084/how-does-firestore-query-operation-strings-treat-different-data-types)
- [How to order data from Firestore in Flutter, orderBy not ordering correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154176/how-to-order-data-from-firestore-in-flutter-orderby-not-ordering-correct)

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer i tried doing, `var newdate = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");  
            console.log("New Date is ", newdate);`. but it returns the date as `yyyy-dd-mm`. Can you please help me convert it to `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: `var parts = "01/15/2020".split("/");
result = parts[2]+"-"+parts[0]+"-"+parts[1];`